# И еще о рубашках

Tags: словообразование

В связи с вопросом предыдущего пользователя у меня возник свой вопрос.
Мы знаем, что правильно говорить "зонтик", хоть в просторечии часто говорят "зонт". А как обстоит дело с рубашкой? Что первично: рубашка или рубаха?
Спасибо

Comment: А можно ссылку на источник, где вариант "зонт" считается просторечным? По-моему, на сегодняшний день этот вариант как минимум допустимый, если вовсе не равнозначный.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно говорить и *зонтик*, и *зонт*. Оба слова литературные и пересекаются в одном из значений. *Зонтик* = *зонт* = приспособление для защиты от дождя или солнца в виде складывающегося и укрепленного на трости каркаса, обтянутого материей.

*Зонтик* еще соцветие.

*Зонт* еще навес над столиком кафе, козырек над балконом, крыльцом, наружной дверью.

А вот *рубаха* - разговорное слово по сравнению с *рубашкой*.